What is the mode of operation of a Hobb's meter?
We have a Hobb's Quartz meter that is connected to a power supply test station that reads the amperage and watts.  It only indicates a reading on the test unit as the unit ticks every few seconds.
What is going on that causes this to only draw power while the unit clicks over the next time increment every few seconds rather than have a constant draw?

The "Quartz" labeling means that time is kept by a quartz crystal oscillator. The oscillator circuit does consume power, but it is a tiny amount (possibly as little as microamps) that your power meter is apparently unable to measure. The mechanical actuator (usually operated every tenth of an hour to advance the indicator mechanism) takes significantly more current, and you power meter is able to show that.
You may have assumed that the meter is more like an old-fashioned clock, moving at all times when powered, driven by a constant-speed motor, but this is not the case. Quartz crystals are significantly more accurate for time-keeping than motors.
If you had a power meter capable of registering sufficiently small amounts of current, you should be able to see the draw of the oscillator circuit when the device is connected (as opposed to zero when it is not connected).
